# Is there an ActionScript library for MP3 encoding than Shine-MP3-Encoder?

Tags: audio, actionscript, mp3, codec

Is there an ActionScript library for MP3 encoding than Shine-MP3-Encoder? (https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy)
This library works fine, but I wanted to find a similar solution (on ActionScript, not C) to optimize it for specific needs.
Thanks.

Comment: @mattytommo - See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dont wait for it. A pure AS3 library is impossible as the speed of AS3 is too slow to do MP3 encoding. You will need C++ via [AIR Native Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) (ANE) or Alchemy for this. ANEs work with Adobe AIR so you can publish your content as an app for desktop and mobile. I dont see any issue with it.

See these for ANE-based Mic recording:

- [ANE-RecordAudio](https://github.com/mani95lisa/ANE-RecordAudio)
- [AirMicrophone](http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/airmicrophone/)
- [AirMicrophone-ANE](https://github.com/j3k0/AirMicrophone-ANE)

Answer (score 1):

I recorded the mic into a WAV and then use `ffmpeg -i d:/path/input.wav d:/path/output.mp3` to convert it instantly into an MP3. I delete the WAV when FFMPEG completes. FFMPEG is a cool little EXE you can just add to your project in any dir. I used [Thibault's class](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3--active-5836) to record into WAV.